# How to make a 2D register/ array in Verilog with variable dimensions

Tags: arrays, variables, 2d, verilog, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm on an FPGA. To generate the initial population for the algorithm I wanted to make a 2D array with user input via switches. However, each time I compile it says that the signal is not a constant. I have tried using integers and parameters which have not worked. I used a state machine to grab the user input and then plan on instantiating the genetic algorithm portion of the code into that module. Below is the module where the GA will live.

```
module your_exam_module(clk, rst, a, b, c, d,e, start, done);

input clk, rst;
input [7:0]a;
input [7:0]b;
input [7:0]c;
input [7:0]d;
input [7:0]e;



input start;
output done;
reg done;



always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (rst == 1'b0)
    begin

        done <= 1'b0;
    end
    else
    begin
        if (start == 1'b1)
        begin
       reg [e-1:0]population[b-1:0]; // generates an E by B register (matrix) that will serve as the initial population
            done <= 1'b1;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Code is now in block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not succeeded because it can not be done.

You are working in HDL which is a Hardware Description Language. There is no hardware which dynamically scales its size up and down. It is like asking a memory chip to dynamically change the amount of bits it can store.

The best you can do is define the biggest, worst case, 2D array you think you will need. Then you can use parts or all of it.

Alternative is to use parameters, but then you have to compile the program each time you need a new size. In fact you are also limited there by the maximum 2D array your FPGA can hold (alongside all your other code).

Comment: That makes sense.Thank you for your help